# Options for SELECTing a column not in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am a beginner in SQL. I have the following 'animal' table:

```
RACE  NAME   AGE
dog   Medor  10
dog   Arthur 17
dog   Pitou  9
cat   Kitty  11
cat   Milo   5
cat   Loki   7
dog   Jack   14
```

I want to write a query to get the maximum age of each race, as well as the name of the associated animal. I tried:

```
SELECT race, name, MAX(age) FROM animal GROUP BY race
```

It does perform the per-race grouping, and does return the maximum age of each race, however, the name of the animal in each race seems random. Basically, it returns

```
RACE  NAME   MAX(age)
dog   Medor  17
cat   Kitty  11
```

whereas I would like it to return

```
RACE  NAME   MAX(age)
dog   Arthur 17
cat   Kitty  11
```

I read about ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and understood SQL will select any value for the NAME column, whereas I expected it to select the value associated with the maximum age.

The only other way I can imagine would be to do a sub-query, but this seems very complicated.

```
SELECT race, name, age FROM animal B WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM animal A WHERE A.race = B.race)
```

I am surprised there is not a simpler solution. I have two questions:

- is it correct my original query should not work (ie. produce the expected result) in the first place?
- is there a better way than doing a subquery?

I'm using MySQL 8.x.

Comment: "...however, the name of the animal in each race seems random..." -- Yes, that's true, because the query is malformed, MySQL does not complain and runs it.

Comment: If you were to use an aggregate like `AVG()` instead of `MAX()` (assuming none of the rows contains exactly the average value), or if you were to use both `MAX()` and `MIN()` in the same select-list, which row should it intuitively return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*,
    row_number() over(partition by race order by age desc) as rn
  from animal a
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: This is a fast reply! Thank you. Still surprised a more simple solution does not exist to select row-wide data when a single aggregate is provided. I think there is room for improvement in SQL!

Comment: avoid using select *.  here in particular, it will include rn which doesn't seem useful

Comment: @andynewman There's a `DISTINCT ON` clause in PostgreSQL that servers this purpose in a rather simpler way. However, that's not part of the SQL Standard and is not implemented in MySQL.